# How to transition from one state to another state based upon distance of agent in a network in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to develop an Agent Based model where patient gets to hospital based on the nearest hospital distance. I have two agent population on Main,

1. patients (Population of 10)
2. hospitals (Population of 2)

This is my network. See Image

[image]

And here is the transition condition,
[image]

distanceTo(getNearestAgent(main.hospitals(0))) < distanceTo(getNearestAgent(main.hospitals(1)))

This is returning the error, "The method getNearestAgent(Iterable) in the type Agent is not applicable for the arguments (Hospital)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `getNearestAgent()` is used for finding the nearest agent in a population and you got the error because you're calling it on a single agent. Since you only have two hospitals that you need to calculate the distance from, you can either use

`distanceTo(main.hospitals(0)) < distanceTo(main.hospitals(1))` *(is hospital(0) closer than hospital(1)?)*

or

`getNearestAgent(main.hospitals).equals(main.hospitals(0))` *(is hospital(0) the nearest one?)*

(But if you need to extend your model to include more than two hospitals, you will need a slightly different approach)

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach to solve your problem:

1. Enter the Patient agent
2. Drag in a function and name it e.g. "goToNearestHospital" and check "Just action (returns nothing) on the radio buttons
3. In the function body, insert the following code:

`Hospital h = this.getNearestAgent(main.hospitals);`

`traceln(h);`

When running the simulation and inspecting the console you should get the nearest hospital returned.

Now, the variable `h` can be passed into the moveTo() method to initiate movement towards the nearest hospital.